# "Property 'Path' does not have a value"

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I'm using the following xaml to fill the dataContext:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

The application works fine, but Cider complains that I must set the Path property.
I'm interested in the entire object, and not a specific property though.

I hope there's a way to get the designer support back!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at section 2.3.8.7 here (you'll need to scroll down a bit):

[Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#Windows%20Presentation%20Foundation%20(WPF)%20Designer%20for%20Visual%20Studio)

Try changing your tag to

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=.}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was just what i need to get my RD working, the fix was from:

```
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

to:

```
CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=.}"
```